# vscode: Multi File Template

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there's a way to specify a template (for the lack of a better word) in vscode that would create multiple files.

In my concrete scenario I want to create an angular component which would contain:

- [mycomp].component.ts
- [mycomp].component.scss
- [mycomp].component.html

Is there a way to do this or am I out of luck?

Comment: Have you considered using angular cli?

Comment: yes, but I want to specify my own template where there would be already some code fragments I often use. As well as the import of my ShareModule and so on...

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1692